# nifi putelasticsearch processor is using published elastic search restful API

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-nifi

I just want to confirm that the nifi putElasticSearch processor calls elastic search restful API under the hood.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Tldr;

Yes it does.

## To understand

The repository is available here,

And as you can [read in here](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/328d38facb25936f8050cb4364757b7994ed3bde/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-elasticsearch-bundle/nifi-elasticsearch-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/elasticsearch/AbstractElasticsearchHttpProcessor.java#L287) they are using the Elastic bulk query